# Can't break python loop

Tags: loops, python-3.6

hi i'm beginner im python,
trying to resolve loop, and can't find any good answer. Nothing seems to be working,
checking for a file in disc c: with two loops, after the chrome.exe is found "for" loop is printing infite path to file, should print it once then go to subprocess. How to terminate loop? i was using break in few places but it terminated code

thank You

```
import sys
import subprocess

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'c:\\'):
    for name in files: 
        if name == 'chrome.exe': 
            pathFile = print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name)))
            subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'mail1.py'])
sys.exit()
```

Comment: show us haw you tried to use break and why it didn't work

Comment: i was trying to break after second for, but it was no use, 
next after if and then after print

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to flag a boolean if you want to break out of the outer loop as well.

```
import sys
import subprocess


found = False #haven't found it yet
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'c:\\'):
    for name in files: 
        if name == 'chrome.exe': 
            found = True #found it
            pathFile = print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name)))
            subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'mail1.py'])
            break #don't look for anymore files
     if found:
         break #don't continue the walk
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Well it's not working either. Still infite loop is on

Answer (score 0):

**It seems the problem occured because of subprocess in next line. And it was looping all time**

---

now i got another problem with module import getting that error :
AttributeError: module 'EmailSender' has no attribute 'senEm'

i have deleted .pyc files

EmailSender.py

```
import smtplib
import Config
import sys


def senEm():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(Config.emailAdr, Config.passWord)
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(Config.subject, Config.msg)
    server.sendmail(Config.emailAdr, Config.emailAdr, message)

    server.quit()
    print('Email sent')
sys.exit()
```

Check.py

```
import os
import sys
import EmailSender

foundFile = 'chrome.exe'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\'):
    for file in files:
        if file == foundFile:
           pathFile = print(os.path.join(root,file))
EmailSender.senEm()
sys.exit()
```

How's that possible, i have renamed files and it's not working still
second problem is that i can't call another file, or function from file